# Difference between Semaphore and wait queue

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Can anyone explain the difference between these two mechanisms, theoretical and implementation perspective in kernel. Can wait queues be used for thread synchronization, if not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Wait queues** are event based mechanism and you wait for particular condition to be true.
       They are not locks.

**Semaphores** are locks. You don't wait on certain condition to be true.

```
    Take lock 
    Process data
    Release lock.
```

Answer (score 4):

Wait queue is already there in the Semaphore structure. Ok , let's understand it in a little detail.

Semaphore structure is as :

```
typedef struct 
{
      int value;
      process *wait_queue;
}
```

Where "value" is the value of the semaphore variable at a time and the "wait_queue" is the list of processes waiting for a resource.Semaphore are of two types :

1. Counting Semaphore
2. Binary Semaphore (Mutex Locks)

Counting semaphore can range in unrestricted domain i.e **Semaphore.value** can range from negative to positive integer. But Binary Semaphore can have values only 0 and 1 . Now we define two operations **wait()** and **signal()** as :

```
wait(Semaphore *S)
{
     S->value--;

     if(S->value < 0)
     {
          Block the process;
          Add it to S->wait_queue;
     }

}

signal(Semaphore *S)
{
       S->value++;

       process *temp = Take a process from "S->wait_queue";
       Change the state of "temp" from block to ready state; 
}
```

So , whenever a process will try to acquire a resource , first of all it will execute **wait()** operation on the semaphore associated with that resource. If that resource is free (or any of the instances of that resource is free) , then resource will be allocated to that process , otherwise process will be blocked and put in the **wait_queue**. If a process leaves a resource then it will execute **signal()** operation and status of one process in the **wait_queue** will be changed from waiting to ready state.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But thats not I am looking for and I don't think binary semaphore and mutex are same as mentioned above.

Comment: I know how they work, I need the difference between them like for example both can be used between thread synchronization, Both move their threads into sleep mode.    By the way below are the structs in found in the kernel.                                                             **`struct __wait_queue_head {
        spinlock_t lock;
        struct list_head task_list;
};`**
**`struct semaphore {
        spinlock_t              lock;
        unsigned int            count;
        struct list_head        wait_list;
};`**

Comment: @srujan i did not say that binary semaphore and mutex are same , you should read my answer again and different OS has different structure for semaphore according to their needs and if it's not the answer to your question then i think i am not  getting what do you want exactly .